# Why does R2-D2's computer interface arm rotate?

Tags: star-wars, droids, r2-d2

In a number of places in the star wars films where we see R2-D2 interface directly with a computer, his interface arm and the socket it plugs into both rotate periodically.

The out-of-universe explanation of this would of course be that it looks cool on film and shows that something is happening, but is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: To expand on the out of universe explanation, the standard images of computers at that time were blinking lights and spinning tape reels. I think they were evoking the latter with R2's spinning.

Comment: Have you ever plugged in a USB device right-side-up on the first try?

Comment: @RyanVeeder, R2's data interface is round.  You don't see it rotating to orient itself before plugging in, it just plugs in *then* things rotate.  Not like a USB port at all.

Comment: Asked and (kinda) answered on Movies:SE - ["Is there any real-world “science” behind R2-D2’s computer interfacing arm?"](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42527/is-there-any-real-world-science-behind-r2-d2-s-computer-interfacing-arm)

Comment: @MontyWild There may be layers involved, or a universal interface that involved rotation. Clearly the plugs were designed round and rotatable.

Comment: [Tape drives](https://youtu.be/Wz6A0bdeUPM?t=168).

Comment: @RyanVeeder usually takes three goes, doesn't it?

Comment: I like to think it's a security or authentication feature, kinda like a key or a safe combination - turn a certain way to identify yourself, or to activate a certain access mode.

Comment: The hackers have gotten so bad in the Star Wars universe that they use combination locks on the computer interfaces. ;-)

Comment: Ohh. So it was R2-D2's _arm_.

Comment: You could ask a similar question about RoboCop's "Spike" interface, which he'd turn like a key after jamming it into whatever interface port he found on the computer he wished to access. That made no real sense either, other that it Just Looked Damn Cool.

Answer (score 6):

These are officially called [scomp links](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scomp_link). They are the standard data interface for the Star Wars universe.

The only explanation is that computers of the day (in-universe) seem to have quite a few physical components to them. For instance, we see in *Rogue One* that the Imperial Archives store data on some sort of drive/tape (this is a deleted scene so you can see the device better)

[image]

We also see Princess Leia get this information onto a data card and put it into R2D2 in ANH.

It's entirely possible that R2D2 is physically having to read "sectors" of data as the arm spins. Need a different set of data? Rotate the interface (just like a hard drive). As manual as these other data devices are, this would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

all data storage technology of the time rotated in some way. hard drives, floppy disks, tape reels, Zip disk, Jazz drive. it rotated the media to the read head. think of it like an old school record.... for that matter you can throw CD's, records, and even mini disk into the list above. they just came up with a "cooler" look for it.

Comment: This would be an out-of-universe explanation. It is not the requested in-universe explanation.

Comment: It is the in-universe explination. All things film related are influenced by real word scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, back in 1977 digital storage of information was not even really a concept yet, in order to access a certain point in memory, you have to move the physical tape with the memory to the read head. R2 does this by spinning the ports with his arm thing. If you want an example of how tape makes a computer work, look up Turing Machines, where there was no CPU chip, just tape rotating in certain ways!